# How do you use C++ 20 modules with classes?

Tags: c++, class, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to use C++20 modules with classes. But I keep getting this error from the compiler:

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This the compiler instruction I used to compile the files:

g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o main airline_ticket.cpp main.cpp

This is the code for airline_ticket.cpp:

```
module;
#include <iostream>

export module airline_ticket;

export class AirlineTicket
{
    public:
        AirlineTicket()
        {
            name = "Unknown";
            km = 0;
            isPremium = false;
        };

        int getKm() { return km; };
        void setKm(int distance) { km = distance; };

        std::string getName() { return name; };
        void setName (std::string nameString) { name = nameString; };

        bool getIsPremium() { return isPremium; };
        void setIsPremium(bool status) { isPremium = status; };

        double price()
        {
            if(isPremium)
                return 0;
            else
                return double( getKm() * 0.20 );
        };
    private:
        std::string name;
        int km;
        bool isPremium;
};
```

And this is the code for main.cpp:

```
import airline_ticket;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    AirlineTicket ticket1;
    ticket1.setName("Leonardo");
    ticket1.setKm(800);
    ticket1.setIsPremium(false);
    double cost { ticket1.price() };
    std::cout << cost << std::endl << ticket1.getKm();
}
```

Any help would very appreciated.

Comment: thats only part of the error message. Please include the complete message

Comment: In `main`, have you tried including <iostream> before importing `airline_ticket`?

Comment: I did what @LaurentLARIZZA said, and the compiler doesn't raise the error anymore, but when i run the program it doesn't work.

Comment: @Leonardopo3130: how does it not work exactly ? What do you get and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Which compiler (name, version, platform)? Note modules support is still quite poor.

Comment: @MarekR Gcc 12.1 windows 10

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA the compilation ends without  problems, but execution finish without printing the result (last line of main.cpp)

Comment: Does this replicate issue you are seeing? https://godbolt.org/z/5Yscbxs95

Comment: @MarekR No, the compiler doesn't raise any error, the only thing i can see now is vs code (not the compiler) saying this message:  the module file for the "airline_ticket" module could not be found.

Comment: `now is vs code (not the compiler) saying this message: the module file for the "airline_ticket"` this is some vital information. So this is more like VS Code plugin issue (so provide name and version of the plugin). Not a compiler issue. AFAIK VS Code plugins uses Clang to parse and lint code (didn't verify that). Support for modules in clang are different and it is not clear which version of Clang plugin uses.

Comment: I am using the C/C++ plugin version 1.10.7